# On a web server, is it normal to see a thousand connections coming from one user?

Tags: web-server, internet, netstat

When I saw so many connections from one IP (by using netstat), I thought it's bot.

(The website is not popular so it's very unlikely to be multiple users behind one IP.)

But I checked apache access log, the paths and user agent of requests from this IP look like normal browsing using a normal browser. Now I'm not sure if it's bot or human.

It's a simple and typical website running on Linux with Apache, Varnish, and PHP. It loads quite some images, css, and js files.

So I'd like to ask experienced web server administrators: If browsing this kind of website using only one browser, is it considered normal or insane to see a thousand connections?

Comment: What browser? Could be a browser issue opening a new htp connection for every little icon. check whether http 1.1 connection reuse is available from your server. It should - it is quite ancient in concept - but mybe somethingblocks it.

Comment: @TomTom chrome 67

Answer (score 0):

Those connections might come from an ISP using CGN, which means that many users share the same IP address.

Comment: How would you see that kind of IP address server-side? The whole point of these is that they are assigned by providers to end-users that are behind a CGNAT, so they are not public IPs. Unless the web server is in the same network as the ISP (which I doubt), the server would only see the public-facing IP(s) of the CGNAT.

Comment: Ah, so true, this was my brainfart :( So, one cannot see if CGN is the reason directly, unless there is some database of CGN public IPs available. Anyway, I think CGN is a good candidate for the phenomenon observed.

Comment: It doesn't even need to be carrier-grade.  I have more than one site with several hundred users behind a single IP address, and several hundred users all hitting the same site at the same time could easily give a thousand connections.